# Запрет редактирования определенных ячеек в DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, .net, datagrid, wpf-datagrid

Есть в DataGrid'е два столбца. Необходимо, чтобы только во 2 столбце нельзя было редактировать определенные ячейки даблкликом.

Comment: Что значит `определенные ячейки`? Вы уж определитесь, или "только во 2 столбце нельзя было редактировать", или "определенные ячейки", это две разные вещи, где первая, например делается простым `IsReadOnly="True"` у соответствующей колонки.

Comment: У первой колонки должен быть запрет на редактирование, а у 2-й колонки только некоторые поля.
Для первой колонки уже сделал в блоке инициализации:
`Datagrid.Columns[0].IsReadOnly = true;`
А вот для 2 колонки пока не смог найти решение.

Comment: `Datagrid.Columns[0].IsReadOnly` - такое сразу забывайте, в WPF этому не место. Хотите использовать так контролы - берите старый WinForms, но в WPF, с его привязками и XAML разметкой... Вы вообще не должны такое хотеть делать. Касательно вашей задачи, делайте тогда [нечто такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53770147/6808809), то есть вы делаете триггер, который проверяет что-то (например `bool` свойство), ну и если триггер срабатывает, то `IsEnabled = false`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить булево свойство отвечающее за необходимость редактирования в класс, из элементов которого состоит ДатаГрид. В самом ДатаГриде забиндить ДатаТриггер в основной контейнер ячейки в нужной колонке на это свойство.

Увы, кода не предоставлено, поэтому точно подсказать сложновато

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Вот фрагменты кода:

 public OpticalPort()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitTables();
            DataGrid.Columns[0].IsReadOnly = true;
            DataGrid.BeginningEdit += DataGrid_BeginningEdit;
        }

private void DataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (e.Row.AlternationIndex != 1)
            //    e.Cancel = true;

        }